# Strange Error C2065: 'ERROR' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, windows

As part of a bigger project ( the ff activex plugin for Mozilla Firefox) there is this code snippet:

```
if (CombineRgn(hrgnClip, hrgnClip, hRGN, RGN_AND) != ERROR)
{
        ::InvalidateRgn(m_hWndParent, hrgnClip, fErase);
}
```

When I build in VS2012 I get "**Error C2065: 'ERROR' : undeclared identifier**"
ERROR is defined in wingdi.h like this:

```
...
/* Region Flags */
#define ERROR               0  // it wont build when this macro is used
#define NULLREGION          1  // it builds when this macro is used
#define SIMPLEREGION        2
#define COMPLEXREGION       3
#define RGN_ERROR ERROR
...
```

The strange thing is that if I replace ERROR (just to see if it builds OK) with NULLREGION or SIMPLEREGION (which are macros in the same file, just two lines below the offending one) in the **if** statement above, the code builds OK. When I use ERROR, the code wont build. 
Is it possible that the ERROR macro defined above gets masked by some keyword or another macro or some such by Visual Studio?

Comment: Try looking current ERROR meaning in a debugger. It could be masked indeed.

Comment: 1) What headers do you include? 2) May be your `ERROR` definition is on the `#ifdef SOME_FLAG`... `#endif` block?

Comment: does `#undef ERROR` appear anywhere after the define? Could be in the file itself or include files included after line?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that ERROR actually appears in the compile error message.  That should not happen, the preprocessor should have substituted it with 0.

So *somewhere* in a .h file you #included after windows.h, some programmer took the 10 second shortcut to a macro name collision problem and wrote this:

```
  #undef ERROR
```

You'd need to find that line and remove it.  That's likely to be difficult and liable to give you a maintenance headache since that's a file you don't own and might well be updated in the future, forcing you to make that change over and over again.  The alternative is to redefine it yourself:

```
#define MYGDIERROR 0
...
if (CombineRgn(hrgnClip, hrgnClip, hRGN, RGN_AND) != MYGDIERROR)
//etc...
```

Which still gives you a maintenance problem and requires you taking a bet that the return value definition of CombineRgn() is never going to change.  That's a very safe bet, GDI is cast in stone.

Comment: Yep, I found **#undef ERROR** in many places. So I used my own macro. BTW GDI_ERROR wont do, already used. Thank you for all your replies!